# Calculate: $\int_0^{\pi}\!\arcsin(\cos^3x)\,dx $

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> How do I solve this: $$\int_0^{\pi}\!\arcsin(\cos^3x)\,dx $$

I tried the substitution $\sin(\cos^3x)=t$ but it didn't lead anywhere.

Comment: Looking at the graph might give a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you shift viz $y=x-\frac{\pi}{2}$, you get a bounded odd function integrated on an interval symmetric about $0$, so the integral is $0$.